# Google Maps API not displaying my markers

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I am currently creating a website for a school project. I have created a code that should display a map with some markers and some lines that represent borders between countries. The problem is that when I load this map I can display the lines but the markers all disappeared. Any help would be very appreciated. I alredy own a valid key.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=MYKEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 768px; height: 512px"></div>
      <form action="#">
        <input type="button" value="hide" onclick="map.removeOverlay(kml)" />
        <input type="button" value="show" onclick="map.addOverlay(kml)" />
      </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(41.8919300, 12.5113300),
        zoom:3,
        streetViewControl: false,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
      var kml = new GGeoXml("http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml");
      map.addOverlay(kml);
      var imageitaly = 'https://MYWEBSITE/mypath/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/italyscaled.png';
      var Rome = {lat: 41.6500086, lng: 12.5113300};
      var markerrm = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Rome,
          map: map,
          title: 'Italia',
       icon: imageitaly
        });
        markerrm.addListener('click', function() {
                window.location.href = ('https://MYWEBSITE/mypath/italia');
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to create a free API key and add it on the link instead of MYKEY http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=MYKEY<<<ADD KEY HERE. You can also try to use a embed Google Map (not a JS Google Map) that doesnt require a API key. Simply copy a embed link from Google Maps.

Comment: I recommend you to use Leaflet instead of Google Maps. Has everything you need, is totally free and is easy to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies but i forgot to say in the post that i alredy own a key and my professor wants me to use the Google Maps api so i'm stuck with that.

Comment: Than add the key after "key=" removing the "MYKEY" text, at the end of the maps.google link